# Обработка событий изменения фокуса

Tags: android, java

Не могу понять, как работает фокус в андроид-приложении. Если сначала была под фокусом вьюшка А, которая находится внутри `PopupWindow`, а потом фокус перешел на вьюшку В, которая находится на самой активити, должен ли вызваться обработчик `onFocusChange` с параметром `focused=false` у вьюшки А?

Comment: Код в студию!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы фокус работал нормально, нужно дописать 2 строчки:

```
yourPopupWindow.setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
yourPopupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```